# Visual Studio Referencing

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, reference, ms-office

I am using C# Winforms and when I add a reference to the project for `Microsoft.Interop.Office.Excel v12.0.0.0`, it automatically adds a COM reference to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.exe`.

This `.exe` isn't found on any other machines, and as such, it won't work on other devices. Is there a way to import that file, or make it not reference to that file?

Comment: using office interop requires office to be installed. there are numerous 3rd party libraries that can read/write excel files.

Comment: You could use *late binding* (which is pretty comfortable way now with `dynamic` types). You can then determine if excel is not installed and your software will run correctly (without being able to use excel though). Another plus, you software may work with other excel versions.

Comment: How does one do a late binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any microsoft office tools like Microsoft.Office.Interof.Excel are part of Microsoft Primary Interop Assemblies called PIA, which can be downloaded separately and installed on production machine.

All version of PIAs can be downloaded from msdn. e.g. [Office PIA](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=3508)

[Msdn Pia link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx)

Or you can copy them to Library Folder in your solution and reference these assembly from Library folder local to your solution.